# Android: "Listening at a high volume may damage your hearing"

Tags: android

My Android app interacts with a card reader via the audio jack, which requires the volume to be turned all the way up. When the volume is increased, users see the following message:

> Listening at a high volume for a long time may damage your hearing. Tap OK to allow the volume to be increased above safe levels.

This message is confusing users because they aren't listening to anything at all. The audio is being used as a data communication channel. I understand you can eliminate this message on a rooted device, but is there anything that can be done on regular non-rooted devices?

Comment: Have you read [this post](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/203278/how-to-disable-warning-about-listening-at-high-volume-for-a-long-time) on Android Enthusiasts? It seems theoretically possible on non-rooted devices since some apps are purportedly able to do so but might require system app permissions. If you find an open source app that can do it it would be a great lead.